# I have the following error " Invalid objects-- ' "cnt-bdb".ors_NGN.tbrder_NN_Op ' "

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT * 
INTO "tygra-01".databasename.new_table_ngn_open
FROM "cnt-bdb".ors_NGN.tbrder_NN_Op
```

Comment: Can you please help me on how to fix that

Comment: `SELECT * INTO [tygra-01].databasename.new_table_ngn_open FROM [cnt-bdb].ors_NGN.tbrder_NN_Op`